# Spring REST URL Encoding Scheme: %20 or + Which one?

Tags: spring, url, rest

I made a Spring REST application where you can perform CRUD operations based on HTTP methods of POST, PUT, GET, DELETE. I have the typical URI template of

```
http://host/root/{id}/{name}/{address} and etc.
```

We have a client who is accessing this REST service. Apparently they are sending parameters for multi-word name and address in the following form:

```
http://host/root/11/John+Smith/10+Las+Vegas+USA
```

They are using the HTML encoding scheme based on application/x-www-form-urlencoded type. According to the article in Wikipedia

> The application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   type
>
> The encoding used by default is based
>   on a very early version of the general
>   URI percent-encoding rules, with a
>   number of modifications such as
>   newline normalization and replacing
>   spaces with "+" instead of "%20". -
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

However it appears the standard URL encoding scheme is to use %20 in replacing spaces in URI templates. Which one is correct?

My Spring REST automatically converts %20 to spaces. It's interpreted correctly. I'm using Spring 3.0.4. When + is met by my REST service, it's accepted as is. Of course when I put validation to exclude +, it is indeed excluded as expected.

Am I within standards or are there such double standards? Or is the client using an ancient scheme?

Answer (score 11):

The point is that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` can be used **only in request parameters**, whereas percent encoding is also supported in a path.

So,

```
http://host/root/11/?name=John+Smith&address=10+Las+Vegas+USA
```

is fine and will be properly decoded by Spring MVC, but

```
http://host/root/11/John+Smith/10+Las+Vegas+USA
```

is wrong and Spring MVC doesn't decode it, because the following form should be used instead:

```
http://host/root/11/John%20Smith/10%20Las%20Vegas%20USA
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I thought. The format "http://host/root/11/John+Smith/10+Las+Vegas+USA" is correct to use when using Spring REST as oppose to Spring MVC.

Comment: With Spring MVC "http://host/root/11/?name=John+Smith&address=10+Las+Vegas+USA" is correct. The format "http://host/root/11/John%20Smith/10%20Las%20Vegas%20USA" is also correct in terms of Spring MVC.

Comment: Now when I told another programmer that we have a REST service why did he assume to use the encoding scheme of application/x-www-form-urlencoded which converts spaces to "+". Isn't this a standard terminology? Or is it my mistake to assume that they know it? Or I am the one who is making the wrong assumption?